PyQt D-BUS add multiple output arguments to the method
I want to add several output arguments in a PyQt5 D-BUS method. I cloned the example from qt example. In class CarInterfaceAdaptor, I added a new method control which has three output arguments: speed, shift and value:
class CarInterfaceAdaptor(QDBusAbstractAdaptor):

    Q_CLASSINFO("D-Bus Interface", 'org.example.Examples.CarInterface')

    Q_CLASSINFO("D-Bus Introspection", ''
            '  <interface name="org.example.Examples.CarInterface">\n'
            '    <method name="accelerate"/>\n'
            '    <method name="decelerate"/>\n'
            '    <method name="turnLeft"/>\n'
            '    <method name="turnRight"/>\n'
            '    <method name="control">\n'
            '      <arg name="name" type="s" direction="in"/>\n'
            '      <arg name="delta" type="i" direction="in"/>\n'
            '      <arg name="speed" type="d" direction="out"/>\n'
            '      <arg name="shift" type="i" direction="out"/>\n'
            '      <arg name="value" type="s" direction="out"/>\n'
            '    </method>\n'
            '  </interface>\n'
            '')

If I used qdbusxml2cpp to compile the above xml. I can get the declaration of control:
double control(const QString &name, int delta, int &shift, QString &value);

The first output argument (speed) is returned by this function, and the other output arguments are defined as output reference arguments (shift and value).
And I wrote and run the an PyQt QDBusAbstractInterface derived class which has the following function:
def control(self):
    message = self.call('control', "car", 2)
    print(message.arguments())
    for arg in message.arguments():
        print(arg)

And I got the following output:
[100.0, 200, 'OK']
100.0
200
OK

In Python, there are not the equivalent output reference arguments for the functions.
However, I can return all these output arguments in a list, like this:
@pyqtSlot(str, int, result=list)
def control(self, name, delta):
    print("name: {}, delta: {}".format(name, delta))
    speed = 100
    shift = 200
    value = "OK"
    return [speed, shift, value]

Now I got the following output.
[[100, 200, 'OK']]
[100, 200, 'OK']

It returns a list not three output arguments! It seems to be wrong. So
Q1: So how can I define control in PyQt D-BUS which can return multiple arguments (like C++) but not a list?
Q2: In PyQt5 D-BUS, I found it still works even if I didn't add the declaration of control in Q_CLASSINFO. So what's Q_CLASSINFO("D-Bus Introspection" ...) for? And, should I have to define Q_CLASSINFO("D-Bus Introspection" ...)?
Thanks!

I'm not sure how it works in Qt, but generally the "introspection" XML is provided for the benefit of clients so that they could obtain the correct types from your service at run time – e.g. dbus-python will make the Introspect() call when a proxy is created, to determine the proper conversion of Python types to D-Bus types.

At last, I found the solution about Q1: using QDBusMessage!.
@pyqtSlot(str, int, QDBusMessage)
    def control(self, name, delta, message):
        print("name: {}, delta: {}".format(name, delta))
        reply = message.createReply([100, 200, "OK"])
        QDBusConnection.sessionBus().send(reply)

